# How can we harmonise 1 Thessalonians 4:16-17 and Hebrews 9 :27?

Tags: contradiction, romans, paul, pauline-epistles, 1-thessalonians

It seems according to Paul some will meet Christ without tasting death

1 Thessalonians 4:16-17 NASB

> [16]For the Lord Himself will descend from heaven with a shout, with the voice of the archangel and with the trumpet of God, and the dead in Christ will rise first.
>   [17]Then we who are alive and remain will be caught up together with them in the clouds to meet the Lord in the air, and so we shall always be with the Lord.

But then Paul also says in another text that all men appointed to die once then judgement

Hebrews 9 NASB

> [27]And inasmuch as it is appointed for men to die once and after this comes judgment,

So how can these seemingly different texts be reconciled?

Comment: Try the contradiction of John 3:16.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enter the kingdom of God we must become spirit:

John 3:5  Jesus answered, "Most assuredly, I say to you, unless one is born of water and the Spirit, **he cannot enter the kingdom of God**.
John 3:6  That which is born of the flesh is flesh, and **that which is born of the Spirit is spirit**.
John 3:7  Do not marvel that I said to you, '**You must be born again**.'

At the return of Christ, a person goes from a physical body (flesh) to a spiritual one. At that time those who are alive will experience a death of the natural body.

1 Corinthians 15:35  But someone will say, "How are the dead raised up? And with what body do they come?"
1 Corinthians 15:36  Foolish one, what you sow is not made alive **unless it dies**.

1 Corinthians 15:44  It is sown **a natural body**, **it is raised a spiritual body**. There is a natural body, and there is a spiritual body.

Even though there are some that will not be dead at the return of Christ, the mortal and corruptible body that they have will need to be discarded so that they may inherit the new glorified immortal body.

So even though this happens in an instant, those that are alive at His coming will also die.

1 Corinthians 15:51  Behold, I tell you a mystery: We shall not all sleep, but **we shall all be changed**—
1 Corinthians 15:52  **in a moment, in the twinkling of an eye**, at the last trumpet. For the trumpet will sound, and the dead will be raised incorruptible, and **we shall be changed**.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible that Hebrews is a general statement to which 1 Thessalonians is a specific, unusual exception. The Hebrews statement is still true for nearly all men.

Comment: Welcome to BH Community. Congrat for a good answer. It is only logical, and Biblical too,  that those saints living  when the Lord comes the death no longer has power!